# Trouble compiling io_uring

Tags: c, linux, io-uring

I have been reading https://kernel.dk/io_uring.pdf and I would like to experiment with the actual syscalls (io_uring_setup, io_uring_enter) to check my understanding, but I am not able to compile the following simple program:

```
#include <kernel/io_uring.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    struct io_uring_params p;
    int ring = io_uring_setup((__u32) 512, &p);
    return 0;
}
```

I get an implicit declaration error for the io_uring_setup function. The man page https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/liburing-dev/io_uring_setup.2.en.html suggests that the only file to include is linux/io_uring.h, but when I look at the source code, I do not see the definition of io_uring_setup.

Comment: It may be the same case as with `futex` syscall: that is, it must be invoked directly using `syscall`.  The idea is to prevent users from trying to use this feature directly unless they really know what they are doing.

Comment: Indeed: https://github.com/axboe/liburing/blob/master/src/syscall.c

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it working using __sys_io_uring_setup. I'm working in the examples/ directory of liburing/ and all I had to do was copy src/syscall.h into src/include/ and "#include syscall.h" in my file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Mid-2021) As [@oakad stated in the comments the `io_uring` syscalls are *not* currently wrapped by libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552233/trouble-compiling-io-uring/68048511?noredirect=1#comment119403975_67552233). If a user wants to invoke raw `io_uring` syscalls (e.g. as described in [`io_uring_setup(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/liburing-dev/io_uring_setup.2.en.html)) it is up to them to provide the additional boilerplate to do so and ensure they obey all the expected rules... Rather than doing everything by hand it looks [easier to use **liburing**](https://github.com/axboe/liburing) (the `io_uring` wrapper library).

I'm unclear on why you chose to use

```c
#include <kernel/io_uring.h>
```

-- this looks wrong. The header on my system is found by

```c
#include <linux/io_uring.h>
```

and the following compiles without error on my system:

```c
/* Needed for memset */
#include <stdio.h>
/* Needed for perror */
#include <string.h>
/* Needed to invoke the syscall */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
/* Needed for io_uring data structures. Compilation will error with a "No such
 * file or directory" on the following include line if your kernel headers are
 * too old/don't know about io_uring. If this happens you have to manually 
 * declare all the io_uring structures/defines yourself. */
#include <linux/io_uring.h>
/* C libraries don't (yet) provide a pretty wrapper for the io_uring syscalls 
 * so create an io_uring_setup syscall wrapper ourselves */
int io_uring_setup(unsigned int entries, struct io_uring_params *p) {
    return syscall(__NR_io_uring_setup, entries, p);
}

int main() {
    int fd;
    struct io_uring_params p;

    memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p));
    fd = io_uring_setup(512, &p);

    if (fd < 0)
        perror("io_uring_setup");

    return 0;
}
```

However as mentioned in [Efficient IO with io_uring PDF](https://kernel.dk/io_uring.pdf) this is just the tip of the iceberg when using `io_uring` via direct syscalls. The [Lord of the io_uring tutorial](https://unixism.net/loti/index.html) has a section titled [The Low-level io_uring Interface](https://unixism.net/loti/low_level.html) which describes the usage in more detail but using `io_uring` looks both easier and safer.

Comment: Thank you. I am surprised this may be an issue, as I am using the most current release of the Oracle UEK (available here: https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/UEKR6/x86_64/). I ended up just looking at the liburing source code and I realized there really is no need to use the syscalls directly.

Comment: Yes, I had a typo in my original question but the code does not compile in either case so I see the need for a wrapper. And I agree that from what I can tell liburing encompasses all the functionality of io_uring.